# Deleting from a sub document in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm making a simple forum where people can make posts and comment on them, however I'm having trouble getting it so people can delete their comments.

This is what I have so far:

```
    <form action="/forum/<%= newPost.id %>/<%= comment.id %>/deletecomment?_method=POST" method="POST" class="d-inline">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="float: right;">Delete</button>
    </form>
```

And this is how I'm trying to delete the comment:

```
router.post('/forum/:postid/:commentid/deletecomment', async function(req, res){ //delete comment
    const Post = await Createpost.findById(req.params.postid)
    await Post.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.commentid)
    res.redirect('/forum/:postid')
})
```

But it's saying Post.findByIdAndDelete is not a function, I'm not sure why though because Post is set to the id of the post in which the comment resides, so it should find the id of the comment and delete it within the post document, no?

Edit: My attempt with the pull function instead, but this won't work either.

```
router.post('/forum/:postid/:commentid/deletecomment', async function(req, res){ //delete comment
    const Post = await Createpost.findById(req.params.postid)
    Createpost.updateOne( {_id: Post}, { $pull: { comments: { _id: req.params.commentid } } } ),
        function (err, user){
        if (err) return next(err);
        User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, user) {
            if (err) return next(err)
            req.flash('success_msg', 'Comment deleted')
            return res.redirect('/forum'), {
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Are you using Mongoose ODM?

Comment: No, I'm not using that

Comment: How does your data model look like - how are you storing the posts and comments data in collections?

Comment: The posts collection has id, text and inside the posts collection, there's an array of objects for the comments. In the comment, there's id and text once again.

Comment: I edited my original post using $pull instead, but it won't work either, and it won't even give me an error :(

Comment: You can use a _filter_ directly in the `updateOne` method. For example, in the code `Createpost.updateOne( {_id: Post}, { $pull: {...`, you can use `{_id: req.params.postid}` instead of `{_id: Post}`. And, you don't need the `findById` method.

Comment: Ah yeah, I should have done that, thank you. But that still didn't fix the problem, the page reloads indefinitely without giving me any kind of error and even in the database, the comment doesn't get removed.

Comment: I suggest try run the code and make it work, and then use it with the route. The usage of [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents).